# How to check result of a query using IF scripting in BigQuery?

Tags: sql, if-statement, google-bigquery

I have a query and I want to check if the output has at least one row, if not , show some message like "No data". I have tried like described here : https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/scripting#if

```
WITH
cte1 AS (
  SELECT id, name
  FROM My_table
)
 SELECT 
* from cte1;
IF (SELECT COUNT(*) = 0 FROM cte1) THEN SELECT "No data"; END IF
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
WITH cte1 AS (
  SELECT id, name
  FROM My_table
)
SELECT id, name
FROM cte1;
UNION ALL
SELECT NULL, 'No Data'
FROM (SELECT 1 as x) x
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM cte2);
```

Note:  The subqueries need to return the same columns.